# I am not what happened to me. I am what I choose to become.

Tags: grammar, sentence, syntactic-analysis

The quote by Carl Jung sounds grammatically incorrect to me. "I am not what happened to me" sounds weird. Is it correct or no?

Answer (score 3):

It makes sense grammatically.

Consider:

- I am not (a bird).
- I am not (what happened to me).

Both bracketed expressions are noun phrases.

Comment: Just a note that traditional grammar analyzes *what happened to me* as a **clause**. Even [ComGEL](https://www.amazon.com/Comprehensive-Grammar-English-Language-General/dp/0582517346) would call it a 'nominal relative clause' (p. 1056). It is the more modern grammars that analyze it as an NP— a fairly complex type of NP at that, a 'fused relative' ([CGEL](https://www.amazon.com/Cambridge-Grammar-English-Language/dp/0521431468), p. 1068).

Comment: @linguisticturn Thank you. Feel free to edit my answer to add detail about the phrase "*what happened to me*".